# How to compare files between two svn revisions in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svn, diff

I know you can `code --diff file1 file2` to use the compare tool in VS code, but is it possible to compare two different svn revisions of a file?

I'd like to be able to combine `svn diff -r 111:222 file1` with `code --diff ...`.

Now `svn diff` would only give me a diff file so it's not enough to compare the whole files in VS code.
I guess I could checkout both revisions of that file and `code --diff` those, but ideally I'd like to do this without the checkout since I'd do this frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following command will help:

```
svn diff -r1000:1001 https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/asf/ --diff-cmd code -x "--wait --diff"
```

You may need to adjust the command line to your needs. Note that the URL is unnecessary if you run svn diff in a working copy. See the following pages for more information:

- [SVNBook | svn diff](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/diff/)
- [SVNBook | Using External Differencing and Merge Tools](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externaldifftools/)

I've just tried the above command and it opens SVN diff in VSCode.
[image]

PS I see the following warning in the command-line output, but I'm unsure of its meaning:

> Warning: 'L' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to
> Electron/Chromium.